# How to use function variable in other functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got functions where i need to work with enterie id . Selecting enterie by id, displaying it and updating rows in DB.
Wont copy all the code, just main idea

controllers

```
function edit_advert()
{
   $id = $this->uri->segment(3); //Here i get my enterie id 
   $this->load->model('model_adverts');
   $myadvert = $this->model_adverts->get_enterie($id); //passing id to model function
 //where i find enterie,  select it from DB and pass it back to controller  
   //and then do if() stuff,  where i give error message or pass returned enterie to
//view and display it .
}

function update_enterie() //in view i got form with values from DB, after editing
//fields, form submits to this function
{ 
   do form validation stuff etc
  And here i need to get $id again and pass it to model, so i can do query update
  where $id = id 
 }
```

So, how i can access that $id variable again ?

Comment: do you have a view with an HTML form that when you submit it it'll go to update_enterie()?

Comment: from experience, the fact that you both functions on one page, the variable $id should automatically be available for use globally... Someone didn't read the PHP manual or actually search the site properly.

Comment: If you want to pass the id between functions either pass it in the function call or set it as an attribute of the controller object.

Kinda basic PHP stuff

Comment: Either put a hidden field with the id in your form and then use `$this->input->post('id')` or `$_POST['id']` *or* pass the id via the URL (just like in the edit example above).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class abc{
    var $id;    
    function edit_advert()
    {
       $this->id = $this->uri->segment(3); //Here i get my enterie id 
       .....
    }
    function update_enterie()
    { 
       //use here $this->id;
    }
}
```

If your `update_enterie()` is not called at the same time then you should use 'session variable'
like,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('my_id', 'value');
```

and use where you want.

Read more http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Update will be a seperate request (form submission), so this is not going to work.

Comment: Why would you use a session for this?? Just pass the id via the form or the URL...